# Why simplexml_load_file does not work relative to host file?

Tags: php, simplexml, relative-path

I have `simplexml_load_file` instruction placed withing included PHP file. But this instruction works depending on where I include this file from. Why? Is it possible to make relative file path be interpreted relatively to the file instruction placed in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always access the current file's full path with the magic [__FILE__](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) constant, so you can write your simplexml_load_file() call like this:

```
<?php
simplexml_load_file(dirname(__FILE__).'/file.xml');
```

#### Update

Since PHP 5.3, there have been a new `__DIR__` introduced, you can use it in place of the `dirname(__FILE__)` like this:

```
<?php
simplexml_load_file(__DIR__).'/file.xml');
```

Comment: But you still don't answer the *why* part.