# simplexml_load_file: Unable to load external entity (called for local path)

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to use the `simplexml_load_file` function in PHP 7.2. I get

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity  "../repositories/some.xml"
```

I went and replaced the call to `simplexml_load_file` with the following:

```
$source = file_get_contents($path);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);
```

and I works perfectly now. (**NOTE** The `$path` is the one that's listed in the error)

Unfortunately I don't have any other information as I have no idea why this could happen. What could be the root of the problem?

Comment: You should inspect the Content of `$source`

Comment: It seems to be the case that external  entities are referenced with relative paths in your Markup. They could not be loaded.

Comment: @steven you mean relative paths?

Comment: @steven could you please be more specific about the content of `$source`?

Comment: First you should post the value of $source... but the error says that the relative path ../repositories/some.xml could not be loaded. So this entity is missing and that is the reason why loading fails.

Comment: But then why does it work with the same path with `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185552/discussion-between-victor-and-steven).

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11468919/811131

Comment: @steven I've also tried absolute paths and the result is the same.

Comment: @steven any other clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem nobody could've found just by reading the question: `mxgraph-php` uses [`libxml_disable_entity_loader`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.libxml-disable-entity-loader.php) without giving any notice and this is what causes the error.

For those using [`mxServer.php`](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/php/src/mxServer.php#L18), you can simply comment/remove the line if you trust the XML files (see [vulnerability example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-disable-entity-loader.php#107730)):

```
libxml_disable_entity_loader(true);
```

If you cannot trust the XML file, you can use `simplexml_load_string` with the processed contents of the file as parameter.

---

<sub>**NOTE** I couldn't have thought of `mxgraph` as the source of this problem and I spent a few hours on this, so I hope it will help people coming from Google with this warning text.</sub>